# VS Code is not showing errors

Tags: javascript, function, visual-studio-code

If I have typed:

```
  var alien1=new AlieNNConstructor("Venus","1511"); instead of var alien1=new AlienConstructor("Venus","1511");
```

Why does Visual Studio Code does not give me an error.
I have experience with Visual Studio and it gives a messege in the error list whenever the code has minor error like non-existing function.
I my case the right function is:

```
function AlienConstructor (alienPlanet1, alienShip1)
  {
      this.alienPlanet=alienPlanet1;
      this.alienShip=alienShip1;
  }
 var alien1=new AlienConstructor("Venus","1511");
```

Why does not VS Code give me an error if I have typed non-existing function like this:

```
function AlienConstructor (alienPlanet1, alienShip1)
  {
      this.alienPlanet=alienPlanet1;
      this.alienShip=alienShip1;
  }
 var alien1=new AlieNNConstructor("Venus","1511");
```

and `AlieNNConstructor(alienPlanet1, alienShip1)` does not exist anywhere! Why does not VS Code give an error??? The just stops working and it's quite strange.
Can I add something like error box to VS Code that is working right?

Comment: have you installed an extension like ESLint?